# Link down & up on my lan setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

Since December I am having some problems with my internet setup at home, with all this Covid-19 pandemic I am very dependent on the internet most because I am a software engineer and I work from home.

I get random disconnects while playing video games after work and sometimes also during my daily work schedule. I thought it was because of the router so I have bought a new one, an Asus RT-AX56U, my old one was a TP-Link pretty cheap something like 40$.

After testing the new router which btw, worked perfectly for the first 2-3 days and I was very happy with it the problem started to happen again. I always have a command prompt window opened with a ping on google and I can see logs like this:

```
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

The log from the router is this one below:

```
Feb 19 21:44:35 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:44:37 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:44:37 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:47:11 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:47:15 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:47:15 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:47:16 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:47:19 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:47:19 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:47:20 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:47:22 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:47:22 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:47:23 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:47:25 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:47:25 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:49:37 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:49:39 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:49:39 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:49:41 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:49:43 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:49:43 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:49:47 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:49:49 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:49:49 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:49:50 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:49:52 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
Feb 19 21:49:52 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link Up at 1000 mbps full duplex
Feb 19 21:49:53 kernel: eth1 (Ext switch port: 0) (Logical Port: 8) (phyId: 0) Link DOWN.
Feb 19 21:49:56 kernel: eth1: sysport_tm port shaper set to 999000 kbps (phy speed 1000000 kbps)
```

My router has default settings, I just set up the wifi password and name and the IPS account and password. Nothing else. My question is, can for example a device from my house trigger the router to do this? This problem as I said started in December, I reinstalled my windows back then, can this impact the router?

I also thought it was from the UTP cables which I made, I have a snuff on the wall that is mounted by me so the path is like this: GPON that converts fiber link to UTP -> router -> snuff on the wall -> UTP cable to PC. The distance is like 4-5 meters so I don't think this should be a huge impact. Please help!

Comment: The issue could be your gear or the ISP equipment. I have had both. Try setting up a temporary Ethernet wire from the ISP modem/router directly to your computer.

Comment: it does sound like a cabling issue. have you configured duplex settings on either end? usually you want to set duplex on both ends, or have it set to autodetect on both ends (so the best bet is to not configure it at all, unless you identify an issue). can you test wiring from the router directly to the workstation?

Comment: @John, if the issue is upstream any further than the router, I don't think op would be seeing disconnect/reconnect messages at the workstation. its link-state wouldn't change unless the connection between the workstation and the router was interrupted. the user might get failures related to the internet, but they wouldn't get link state changes just because the internet failed 2 connections upstream.

Comment: Indeed I will test it with a direct-wired connection from the IPS equipment and from the router and see which one cause the problem. I will keep you up to date, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The frequent *link up* and *link down* on eth1 are caused by a flaky cable. Replace.

Also check whether the interface throws frequent errors (e.g. `netstat -e` for Windows). If those errors are higher than zero that's another indication for a faulty cable. (You seem to be using 1000BASE-T where errors show up on both ends. 10BASE-T/100BASE-TX use only a single pair per direction, so transmission errors can be limited to one side.)

While a patch cable is easier replaced than tested, a walled cable and sockets not so. You can best test those - one stretch at a time - by connecting two computers/laptops and running a load test (e.g. using iperf3). If no errors are received, the connection should be fine.

Regarding the impact for just 4-5 meters: some cable problems (discontinuities, shorts, pair mismatch) can happen regardless of length. Sub-standard cables (just voice-grade or Cat 3) are less of a problem on very short runs (<< 10 m) but not advisable anyway.